# Access @property decorator in model

Tags: python, django

If I have a property like this in my models.py

```
@property
def count_card_holders(self):
    count = 0
    for branch in self.branches.all():
        count = count + branch.card_holders.count()

    return count
```

How would I use the `count_card_holders()` function in my views.py?

I can access it just fine in my template by using `{{cardholder_detail.branch.count_card_holders}}`

Comment: Without the parentheses. `instance.count_card_holders`  will suffice. Notice that the property (hence the name) is no longer a callable (function).

Comment: Note, this code is pretty inefficient, you should look into aggregations.

Comment: Also, the `@` is a decorator, not an annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count_card_holders` by using it with that data modal object in views.

For example:

`views.py`

```py
x = ModalName.objects.get(key=key)

y = x.count_card_holders
```